# mysql trigger Update a row after insert according to condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am writing a MySQL trigger. In which I would like to update branch_form_no with auto increment form number according to branch id. How should I do?

I have table hcm_staffing_applicantform with columns id, applicant_name, etc, etc, branch_id, branch_form_no

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_branch_appform
AFTER INSERT ON branch_form_no
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF branch_id = 1 then
    UPDATE hcm_staffing_applicantform
    SET branch_form_no = ((SELECT max(branch_form_no) from hcm_staffing_applicantform where hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_id=1) + 1)
    WHERE hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_form_no = NEW.branch_form_no;
ELSEIF branch_id = 2 THEN
    UPDATE hcm_staffing_applicantform
    SET branch_form_no = ((SELECT max(branch_form_no) from hcm_staffing_applicantform where hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_id=1) + 1)
    WHERE hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_form_no = NEW.branch_form_no;
ENDIF
```

I also tried this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_branch_appform
AFTER INSERT ON hcm_staffing_applicantform
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE hcm_staffing_applicantform
    SET branch_form_no = ((SELECT max(branch_form_no) from hcm_staffing_applicantform where hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_id= NEW.BRANCH_ID) + 1)
    WHERE hcm_staffing_applicantform.branch_form_no = NEW.branch_form_no;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but NOT working..... anyone? please

Comment: What is the issue with your trigger?  I mean, apart from obvious things like no `delimiter` statement and no `end`.

Comment: is there a way to update without if ?